# How do I decode an Apache Thrift payload in Go?

Tags: go, thrift

This is the working JavaScript version of what I'm trying to do in Go.

```
let next = TBufferedTransport.receiver(data => {

 let proto = new TCompactProtocol(data)
 let ae = new AnalyticEventBatch()

 ae.read(proto)
});
```

Using Go, I can't get Thrift to decode the payload - what should I be doing?

Comment: Is the payload json?

Comment: Also, please post what you've already tried in `GO`

Comment: Check out gRPC. http://www.grpc.io/faq/

Comment: @OliverQueen no the payload is binary

Comment: @voutasaurus i'm receiving the data from Kafka - i don't have control over the transport layer

Comment: have you ventured into this? https://github.com/Shopify/sarama

Comment: @Rebecca Are you using the generated code from the thrift-go compiler?

Comment: @sberry Yes, I've got the generated code. I've got a byte array, and the generated code, and I don't know how to convert the byte array into the thrift object.

Comment: @Rebecca if you have the `[]byte` slice, you probably will be doing something like this: https://github.com/glycerine/golang-thrift-minimal-example/blob/master/serialize.go#L35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data []byte //that's the byte array you received

transp := &TMemoryBuffer{Buffer: bytes.NewBuffer(data)}
proto := NewTCompactProtocol(transp)

ae := NewAnalyticEventBatch()
ae.Read(proto)
```

It would be cleaner if you could read from file/socket directly. Then you would only need thrift `StreamTransport`

Comment: You have a small typo: `proto := thrift.NewTCompactProtocol(transp)`, but otherwise this worked perfectly!